# Cannot resolve symbol 'Log' in android Library

Tags: android, wear-os

I created a library shared by my wearable app and my mobile app. I wanted to do some logging but am getting an error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Log'
```

when I add:

```
import android.util.Log
```

in a class I created. I suspect I need to add something to the library's build.gradle but have not been able to find it.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

sourceCompatibility = "7"
targetCompatibility = "7"
```

**UPDATE**

There are two types of modules, Android or Java/Kotlin. I was watching [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzC-FXeZiIk) and this was mentioned along with primary reasons for choosing one over the other. The main one being user of Android components vs re-use w/other platforms (e.g. iPhone).

I don't really need any other Android component aside from the Log. Is there any way to log to Logcat without having to include:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

Comment: It's hard to answer without your build.gradle to look at.  Can you create a new module from the Android Studio wizards so it adds everything for you?

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Specifically you at least need the following to access classes like Log

```
  plugins {
      id 'com.android.library'
  }
```

This will build your library as an AAR file and include.  This particularly dependency comes from the Android SDK, not from a gradle dependency.

[image]

Comment: I tried replacing the "apply plugin: 'java-library'", but that did not work. The next error I got was "compileSdkVersion is not specified". Do you have an example of a bare bones build.gradle with the edit you specified that will compile?

Comment: Use android studio and generate one. It's described in the linked article with pictures for each step.

Comment: I think the big decision is if I convert this to an android library from a java library.